# Problem calculating difference between 2 dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, time

I cannot figure out how to get the difference in numbers of days between 2 given dates. I searched google and several forums for answers and tried to apply several codes but all of them give me a TypeError.

```
spx_test = pd.read_csv('5_12_2019 S&P500 test1.csv')
spx_test.drop(['optionid','index_flag','issuer','exercise_style'], axis= 1, inplace = True)

spx_test
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR67K.png)

Then I changed the format of the date and want to calculate the difference ['days'].

```
spx_test["date"] = pd.to_datetime(spx_test["date"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
spx_test["exdate"] = pd.to_datetime(spx_test["exdate"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

pd.to_datetime(spx_test['date'])
pd.to_datetime(spx_test['exdate'])
spx_test['days'] = spx_test['exdate'] - spx_test['date']
```

It tells me "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'", which makes sense to me if the 2 columns are still strings but I thought that pd.to_datetime takes my Ymd string and turns it into a date I can use operators on.

Total python newbie here, so let me know what I am not seeing. Thanks!

Comment: you actually haven't assigned the datetime object to a column, you've just called it. change `pd.to_datetime(spx_test['date'])` to `spx_test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(spx_test['date'])` better yet, remvoe the `dt.strftime` method no point creating a date then converting it back to a string?

Comment: I was typing something similar, so what they said ^^^ :).  Plus you'll want `spx_test['days'] = (spx_test['exdate'] - spx_test['date']).dt.days`.

Comment: Thank you guys, Manakin and Rick M, especially for the .dt.days approach, which gives me just the days as integer. Really useful! Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error `"unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'"` is telling you that you are using strings (str) instead of a date

if you do

```
spx_test["date"] = pd.to_datetime(spx_test["date"])
spx_test["exdate"] = pd.to_datetime(spx_test["exdate"])

spx_test['days'] = spx_test['exdate'] - spx_test['date']
```

Then you should get the difference of dates in days

All of this assuming your dates are in standard form and pd.to_datetime has no problems